# python: to display the unique elements in the list

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to this python language: I am facing issues to display the unique elements in the list in the following pgm: Below are my program:

```
def unique_list(lst):
    c = []
    for i in lst:
        if (lst.count(i)>=1) & i not in c:
            c.append(i)
            #print(c)
    return c  
print(unique_list([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]))
```

I received the output as:

`[1,2,2,4]` instead of `[1,2,3,4,5]`

i think there is a mistake in the if stmt... can anyone explain me y am i getting this output??

Comment: You can use `set` ex: `print(set([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]))`

Comment: Use `and`, not `&`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Most people here would greatly appreciate it if you would spend a bit more effort in asking your question. After all, it takes some effort to read and answer it, too. Examples include: Do not use hard-to-read abrreviations ("stmt", "pgm", "y"…), format your code, …

Comment: I don't think you need the first part in your if statement anyway: just `if i not in c` should be enough, since`i` will always be an element of `lst`, and thus `lst.count(i)` is always equal or larger than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique elements in a list by transforming it into a set:

```
print(set([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5]))
```